How do I exit black blank screen (Ctrl+Alt+F3) on SteamOS?
I pressed Ctrl+Alt+F3 as this is a shortcut key for one of the programs that I am using and when I pressed this, all four of my screens went black and blank.
I don't know how to get back to my normal desktops. Pressing the power button on the Steam Deck doesn't seem to do anything. It stays black and blank.
Pressing Ctrl+Alt+F3 again doesn't return me back to my normal desktop.
I've also plugged out my external monitors, keyboard, mouse, and all of my stuff via Type C, but I still have the same issue. The screen is just black and blank. There's literally nothing on the screen.
I found some other people online complaining about this too and they're saying to press Ctrl+Alt+F7 which I've done, but nothing happens.

How do I exit this black blank screen (Ctrl+Alt+F3) on SteamOS and return back to my normal KDE desktop environment?

Solution 1:
Press Ctrl+Alt+F1. This worked for me.
Solution 2:
If solution 1 doesn't work, then unplug all USB devices and hold down the power button until the Steam Deck turns completely off. When it turns back on after this long power button press, it'll be back into Gaming Mode, and then you can just switch back to Desktop Mode and you'll have everything back to normal.

Solution 1 is good: https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Linux_console#Keyboard_shortcuts
